# How can I access my GMail contact groups from my iOS 7 device?

Tags: ios, contacts, gmail

I really need to be able to access contact groups in the Contacts app on my iOS 7 device. How can I do this? In the side bar, all that is available is "All GMail", nothing else. However, under iCloud, there are several groups. Suggestions?

Comment: You mean suggestions other than "use iCloud not Gmail"?

Comment: Yes @DanielLawson, other than iCloud. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here was my final solution. I used [Contacts Sync for Google Gmail](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/contacts-sync-for-google-gmail/id686378579?mt=8). Great little app, and you can try it free. The only issue I have with it is that it doesn't automatically sync. I have to manually sync it. If someone comes up with an automatic way of syncing, I will gladly accept that answer over mine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like they've added auto sync as an IAP in Mar 2014. You might want to update your answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the (becoming deprecated) exchange-based sync that gmail used never did it.  And the newer carddav sync doesn't support it "yet". I believe the spec they wrote for the protocol does provide the means for contact groups, but google simply has not implemented everything yet.

Google  does provide such features in their APIs which is a long way of saying you can find a few third-party solutions at the AppStore for the time-being that will sync your gmail groups bi-directionally.  Not sure if there are any free ones and haven't tried any to recommend, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmmm...okay. Thanks; very helpful. However, I can't accept it 'cuz it isn't a complete solution.

Comment: :-D well ill update it when it's possible!

Answer (score -2):

I use www.memotoo.com I love it as I can sync my contacts from linkedin, xing, fb etc. with my google account and my devices and groups are taken into my contacts on the iPhone, iPad and Mac.
If I open the address book, synching is done automatically.
It is not free but really worth the 1€ a month :-)

Comment: This reads like an advertisement. A bad advertisement.